# in R how to filter lines containing substring?

Tags: r

I'm reading lines in `R`

```
lines = readLines("mylog.log")
```

How can I filter and get only the lines containing `Controller`?

I tried something like:

```
filter[grep("Controller")]
```

but I get:

```
argument "pattern" is missing, with no default
```

So then:

```
lines[grep(pattern="Controller")]
```

but then getting:

```
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

but `x` is the line itself, What am I missing? I want to specify only the pattern!

Comment: What is the resulting object? A data.frame? A character vector? Check `?grep`, but in short, `grep(pattern = "Controller", x = lines)` could get you started.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik excellent then with `lines[c(grep(pattern = "Controller", x = lines))]` I could get back the filtered lines!

Comment: `grep` takes 2 arguments. The pattern that you want to detect, and the string within which you want to search for that pattern.

Comment: @sotos yeah looks like i need to get used to `functional` style from `OOP` when using `R`!!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik can you please post it as answer so I accept it?

Comment: or you can choose mine @Jas :D...again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the argument to which apply the regular expression, `lines`.

```
grep(pattern = "Controller", x = lines)
```

This results in a vector of indices where `Controller` appears, which you can use to subset.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` function takes as arguments `(pattern, x, ...)` "Controller" as the `patern` argument should be enough but then indicate which string should the function look into for example `line[0]`